# Storage and costs

Tags: storage

I have tried a google search but with no luck as to what the costs are for storing content on the Tezos blockchain, if these costs are kept on a level if the price of XTZ goes up, plus what are the simple (I'm not a coder so simple is the word here) mb of data that I can store and how much can this be changed - ie store a text file of what size.

Many thanks,

Dominic

Answer (score 5):

Storage cost per byte is defined in [protocol constants](https://tzkt.io/PsDELPH1Kxsxt8f9eWbxQeRxkjfbxoqM52jvs5Y5fBxWWh4ifpo/constants) (see "Byte cost"). For the current protocol it's `0.00025` tez per byte that means you will pay **~262 tez** for storing **1MB** of data. Note: this value can be changed in following protocols.

You can store any amount of data in lazy storage (aka `big_map`), however there are "Hard operation storage limit" = 60,000 bytes (this value can also be changed), that means if you want to write a large amount of data, you will have to split it into ~60KB chunks.